# Manipulating dataframe columns

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to manipulate. Here's an example of the data:

[image]

As you can see we have 3 columns. Column `proteins` has multiple elements separated with a comma, whereas column `term description` only has a single element per row. My aim is to reverse this and have a column with single elements from `proteins` and another column with multiple elements from `term description`. To explain this by an example if proteins `CYP51A1` fall under the `term description` `metabolic process` and `organic substance metabolic process` I want my dataframe to look like this:

```
protein_name | term description
---------------------------------------------------------------------
CYP51A1      | metabolic process, organic substance metabolic process
etc.
```

i hope i explained this good enough! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it via pandas explode and apply methods.

Let's create a sample dataframe first.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'term description': ['metabolic process', 'organic substance metabolic process', 'metabolic process a', 'metabolic process b', 'metabolic process c'],
                         'false discovery rate': [1.01, 1.001, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04],
                         'proteins': ['CYP51A1,CPA1,STK10', 'CYP51A1,CPA1,AAA', 'CPA1,AAA,BBB,CCC', 'AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD', 'AAA,CCC,EEE,FFF']
                        })

# dataframe df1
    term description                    false discovery rate    proteins
0   metabolic process                   1.010                   CYP51A1,CPA1,STK10
1   organic substance metabolic process 1.001                   CYP51A1,CPA1,AAA
2   metabolic process a                 1.020                   CPA1,AAA,BBB,CCC
3   metabolic process b                 1.030                   AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD
4   metabolic process c                 1.040                   AAA,CCC,EEE,FFF
```

Let's split the proteins column to a list, so that we can explode it.

```
df1['proteins'] = df1['proteins'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
df1 = df1.explode('proteins')

# dataframe df1         
    term description                    false discovery rate    proteins
0   metabolic process                   1.010                   CYP51A1
0   metabolic process                   1.010                   CPA1
0   metabolic process                   1.010                   STK10
1   organic substance metabolic process 1.001                   CYP51A1
1   organic substance metabolic process 1.001                   CPA1
1   organic substance metabolic process 1.001                   AAA
2   metabolic process a                 1.020                   CPA1
2   metabolic process a                 1.020                   AAA
2   metabolic process a                 1.020                   BBB
2   metabolic process a                 1.020                   CCC
3   metabolic process b                 1.030                   AAA
3   metabolic process b                 1.030                   BBB
3   metabolic process b                 1.030                   CCC
3   metabolic process b                 1.030                   DDD
4   metabolic process c                 1.040                   AAA
4   metabolic process c                 1.040                   CCC
4   metabolic process c                 1.040                   EEE
4   metabolic process c                 1.040                   FFF
```

Now we'll combine the values under 'term description' that belongs to the same protein.

```
df2 = df1.groupby('proteins')['term description'].apply(list).reset_index()

# dataframe df2
    proteins    term description
0   AAA         [organic substance metabolic process, metaboli...
1   BBB         [metabolic process a, metabolic process b]
2   CCC         [metabolic process a, metabolic process b, met...
3   CPA1        [metabolic process, organic substance metaboli...
4   CYP51A1     [metabolic process, organic substance metaboli...
5   DDD         [metabolic process b]
6   EEE         [metabolic process c]
7   FFF         [metabolic process c]
8   STK10       [metabolic process]
```

Now, all we need to do is to apply a lambda that'd modify the 'proteins' column values as per our requirements. I'm adding a sample one based on what you mentioned. You can add multiple conditions inside this method as you need.

```
def modifier(protein, term_descrip):
    if protein == 'CYP51A1' and set(term_descrip).intersection({'metabolic process', 'organic substance metabolic process'}):
        return 'CYP51A1 etc.'
    # add more if conditions as required

df2['proteins'] = df2.apply(lambda row: modifier(row['proteins'], row['term description']), axis=1)

# dataframe df2
    proteins        term description
0   None            [organic substance metabolic process, metaboli...
1   None            [metabolic process a, metabolic process b]
2   None            [metabolic process a, metabolic process b, met...
3   None            [metabolic process, organic substance metaboli...
4   CYP51A1 etc.    [metabolic process, organic substance metaboli...
5   None            [metabolic process b]
6   None            [metabolic process c]
7   None            [metabolic process c]
8   None            [metabolic process]
```